# Saving Values to Backend from TextBoxes using React Flux Pattern

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, flux

I have several text boxes and a save button

[image]

Each text box value is loaded using the following approach

```
   {
   this.getElement('test3lowerrangethreshold', 'iaSampling.iaGlobalConfiguration.test3lowerrangethreshold',
   enums.IASamplingGlobalParameters.ModerationTest3LowerThreshold)
   }

private getElement(elementid: string, label: string, globalparameter: enums.IASamplingGlobalParameters): JSX.Element {
        let globalParameterElement =
            <div className='row setting-field-row' id={elementid}><
                span className='label'>{localeHelper.translate(label)}</span>
                <div className="input-wrapper small">
                    <input className='input-field' placeholder='text' value={this.globalparameterhelper.getDataCellContent(globalparameter, this.state.globalParameterData)} />
                </div>
            </div>;
        return globalParameterElement;
    }
```

**Helper Class**

```
class IAGlobalParametesrHelper {

    public getDataCellContent = (globalparameter: enums.IASamplingGlobalParameters, configdata: Immutable.List<ConfigurationConstant>) => {
        return configdata?.find(x => x.key === globalparameter)?.value;
    }
}
```

This works fine. Now the user is allowed to update these text values.And on click of save the changes should be reflected by calling a web api .
I have added an onlick event like this

```
<a href='#' className='button primary default-size' onClick={this.saveGlobalParameterData}>Save</a>
```

Now inorder to save the data i need a way to identify the text element which has changed.For that i have added an update method within the **Helper** class

```
public updateCellValue = (globalparameter: enums.IASamplingGlobalParameters, configdata: Immutable.List<ConfigurationConstant>,updatedvalue:string) => {
        let itemIndex = configdata.findIndex(x => x.key === globalparameter);
        configdata[itemIndex] = updatedvalue;
        return configdata;
    }
```

and return the updated `configdata` ,and i plan to call this method in the `onchange` event of every text box like this

```
<input className='input-field' placeholder='text' onchange={this.setState({ globalParameterData: this.globalparameterhelper.updateCellValue(globalparameter, this.state.globalParameterData, (document.getElementById(elementid) as HTMLInputElement).value})}
```

But this does not seem like a correct approach as there are number of syntactical errors. I initially got the data using an actioncreator like this.Please advice.

```
samplingModerationActionCreator.getGlobalParameters();    
samplingModerationStore.instance.addListener(samplingModerationStore.SamplingModerationStore
        .IA_GLOBAL_PARAMETER_DATA_GET_EVENT,
        this.getGlobalParameterData);
}
```